# on every postback page opens in a new tab

Tags: asp.net

I have a weird problem in my page. I have a button called Print. I wanted report should come in a new tab, so i wrote some javascript on button's onClientClick. Which works great with no problem at all.

But problem starts now when user comes back on original page again, now here i have several controls which cause postback. Say for example its a dropdownlist. so whenever user changes dropdown item it causes postback which is fine but everytime it opens a new tab on every postback.

hope I am clear in question...

Any help??

Here is a code:

```
<asp:Button ID="btnshow" runat="server" Text="Show" Font-Bold="true" ForeColor="Black" Width="90px" OnClick="btnshow_Click" OnClientClick ="document.forms[0].target = '_blank';"/>
```

Answer (score 2):

The issue is `document.forms[0].target='_blank'` is setting the target on the form not the individual button so a postback triggered by any control will open in a new tab.

**You should use a [HyperLink](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.web.ui.webcontrols.hyperlink?view=netframework-4.7.2) control instead of the [Button](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.web.ui.webcontrols.button?view=netframework-4.7.2) control**. The [HyperLink](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.web.ui.webcontrols.hyperlink?view=netframework-4.7.2) control has a [Target](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.web.ui.webcontrols.hyperlink.target?view=netframework-4.7.2#System_Web_UI_WebControls_HyperLink_Target) property which allows you to specify how the link should be opened.

Below is an [example taken from the HyperLink documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.web.ui.webcontrols.hyperlink.target?view=netframework-4.7.2#examples). This will render an [anchor tag](https://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_a.asp) with `target="_blank"`.

```
<asp:HyperLink ID="lnkPrint" NavigateUrl="http://www.microsoft.com" Text="Print" Target="_blank" runat="server" />
```